# Choose the greater of either left or right side of 2 queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following union query that queries for the most recent date of a column if it exists:

```
SELECT TOP 1 m.sentdate AS 'calltreelastsignedoff' 
FROM Incidents i 
INNER JOIN Plans p ON i.planuid = p.uid 
INNER JOIN IncidentMessages im ON i.uid = im.incidentuid 
INNER JOIN Messages m ON im.messageuid = m.uid 
WHERE p.uid = '031E3346-2921-426E-9494-1111111111' 
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 m.sentdate AS 'calltreelastsignedoff' 
FROM Incidents i
INNER JOIN PlanExercises pe ON i.planexerciseuid = pe.uid
INNER JOIN IncidentMessages im ON i.uid = im.incidentuid 
INNER JOIN Messages m ON im.messageuid = m.uid 
WHERE pe.planuid = '031E3346-2921-426E-9494-1111111111'
```

This will return 2 values if each query returns a top 1 result.

What I really want is to select the top 1 of the combined query.

How can I perform a select on the unioned query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

You could do this with a derived table

```
select top 1 from
(   
  SELECT TOP 1 m.sentdate AS 'calltreelastsignedoff' 
  FROM Incidents i 
  INNER JOIN Plans p ON i.planuid = p.uid 
  INNER JOIN IncidentMessages im ON i.uid = im.incidentuid 
  INNER JOIN Messages m ON im.messageuid = m.uid 
  WHERE p.uid = '031E3346-2921-426E-9494-1111111111' 

  UNION

  SELECT TOP 1 m.sentdate AS 'calltreelastsignedoff' 
  FROM Incidents i
  INNER JOIN PlanExercises pe ON i.planexerciseuid = pe.uid
  INNER JOIN IncidentMessages im ON i.uid = im.incidentuid 
  INNER JOIN Messages m ON im.messageuid = m.uid 
  WHERE pe.planuid = '031E3346-2921-426E-9494-1111111111' 
)a
order by <col>
```